# Dedekind Cuts: Is This A Typo?

Tags: real-analysis

*Definition*: Let $a$ **rational cut** in $\mathbb{Q}$
  be of the form $A\mid B=\{r\in\mathbb{Q}:r<q\}\mid\{r\in\mathbb{Q}:r\geq q\}$
  where $q\in\mathbb{Q}$.

*Definition*: The cut $x=A\mid B$
  is **less than or equal** to othe cut $y=C\mid D$
  if $A\subset C$ .

The following is an exert from a Mathematical Analysis text:

"We write $x\leq y$ if $x$  is less than or equal to $y$
  and we write $x<y$
  if $x\leq y$ and $x\neq y$. If $x=A\mid B$
  is less than $y=C\mid D$
  then $A\subset C$
  and $A\neq C$
 , so there is some $c_{0}\in C\setminus A$
 . Since the $A$-set of a cut contains no largest element, there is also a $c_{1}\in C$
  with $c_{0}<c_{1}$ 
 . All the rational numbers $c$
  with $c_{0}\leq c\leq c_{1}$
  belong to $C\setminus A$
 . Thus, $x<y$
  implies that not only is $C\setminus A$
  non-empty, but it contains infinitely many elements ".

It should be $c_{0}\leq c<c_{1}$
 right ? If we let $A=\{a\in\mathbb{Q}:a<q_{0}\}$
  and $C=\{c\in\mathbb{Q}:c<q_{1}\}$
  then $C\setminus A=\{c\in\mathbb{Q}:\mbox{ }q_{0}\leq c\mbox{ and }c<q_{1}\}$, that is that $C\setminus A=\{c\in\mathbb{Q}:\mbox{ }q_{0}\leq c <q_{1}\}$.  Therefore, it should say " All the rational numbers $c$ with $c_{0}\leq c<c_{1}$ belong to $C\setminus A$." Right? Either way it wouldn't change the fact that $C\setminus A$ has infinetly many elements, but it would make it so there is a least element in $C\setminus A$.

Also, I am a little confused; A Dedekind cut in $\mathbb{Q}$ is a singleton set right? Thanks for your time.

Comment: I believe that the text is correct. You are right in your determination of $C \setminus A$, but note that your $q_{1}$ does *not* belong to $C$, whereas $c_{1}$ does by construction, so that $c_{1} < q_{1}$.

Comment: "We write $x<y$ if $x<y$ and $x\neq y$." I'm pretty sure the second $x<y$ should be $x\le y$.

Comment: It’s fine: $c_1$ is chosen to belong to $C$, so the entire rational interval $[c_0,c_1]\cap\Bbb Q$ is contained in $C$.

Comment: No, a Dedekind cut in $\Bbb Q$ is definitely not a singleton set. In your notation it’s an ordered pair of non-empty subsets of $\Bbb Q$, written $A\mid B$, such that $a<b$ for each $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, $A\cup B=\Bbb Q$, and $A$ has no largest element. In some other versions of the construction the set $A$ would be called the Dedekind cut, but it still is never a singleton set.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott  Yeah that is what the book said, i guess the part that confused me is that we let $x=A\mid B$ which made me start thinking of cut as an element. Thanks.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti I didn't think about that! Thanks, it is clearer to me now.

Comment: You’re welcome. The cut actually **is** a single element of the set of Dedekind cuts, i.e., of the set of real numbers that you’re constructing; it’s just that it also has a rather complicated internal structure in its own right, a structure that we forget about completely after we’ve constructed the reals and proved that they have the expected properties.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott OK, now it is starting to make sense. Thanks.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott OK,I am still confused.See we knew that we could find a $c_{1} > c_{0}$ simply because $C$ has no maximum, by the definition of a cut. Now, I know that in order for the relation $c_{0}<c_{1}$ to be true the relation $c_{0}\leq c_{1}$ must also be true; so it if fair to digress and write that  $c_{0}\leq c\leq c_{1}$, but this doesn't really tell me much, without knowing for sure that there is an infinite amount rational numbers between any two rational number. At any rate it is necessary that  $c_{0}<c_{1}$ for the aforementioned to be true. So, why write $c_{0}\leq c\leq c_{1}$,

Comment: @Jimmy: You’re quite right that we need to be sure that $c_0<c_1$. However, the fact remains that every rational number between **and including** $c_0$ and $c_1$ is in $C$, so it’s true that $[c_0,c_1]\subseteq C$. That $c\in C$ whenever $c_0\le c\le c_1$ is just another way of saying the same thing. The point of the $\le$ signs is that we allow $c$ to be $c_0$ or $c_1$; the fact that $c_0<c_1$ isn’t expressed in the relation $c_0\le c\le c_1$, but we know it because we chose $c_1>c_0$. You can’t write a single inequality that says both that $c$ can be $c_0$ or $c_1$ **and** that $c_0<c_1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott OK, now it makes more sense! I sometimes read too much into the semantics of mathematical symbols, to the point that I forget everything else going on around the symbol. But I still have one uncertainty, is there a least element in $C\setminus A$?

Comment: @Jimmy: Yes, narrow focus can sometimes be a problem as well as (sometimes) a help. When in doubt, a reasonable first step is to look back to see whether there’s extra information at hand that clears up the confusion.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks, for the advice. I don't know if you got my last question (i edited my previous comment). I have one last uncertainty, is there a least element in $C\setminus A$?

Comment: @Jimmy: It depends on whether the cut represents a rational number or not. If $p\in\Bbb Q$, the cut $A\mid B$ corresponding to $p$ is $A=\{q\in\Bbb Q:q<p\}$, $B=\{q\in\Bbb Q:q\ge p\}$; in this case $p$ is the least element of $C\setminus A$. If $A\mid B$ represents an irrational number, however, $B$ has no least element, and therefore $C\setminus A$ also has no least element.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott That makes perfect sense. Thanks a lot, I can now comfortably move on to page 14 in my book.

Comment: @Jimmy: Excellent! You’re welcome.